# Is there any way to add data to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension where I need to add data to user's clipboard , so that he/she only needs to press cmd + V / ctrl + V to paste, wherever they want.

Its only about Chrome, no browser compatibility required.

Can I do it with JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome used to have this support by default, but security changes to Webkit prevented it, even for extensions.  It sounds like it is possible with a workaround though, described here:
http://fartersoft.com/blog/2010/11/20/accessing-operating-system-clipboard-in-chromium-chrome-extensions/